# Horizontal RecyclerView scroll left or right if there are more items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I need to build a horizontal recyclerview that will scroll left or right depending on user's select item.

For example imagine an adapter that holds 10 items and only five are visible.

if user tap on position 5 i need to scroll to position + 1 and backwards.

Any idea how to implement this algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation:

```
For example imagine an adapter that holds 10 items and only five are visible.

if user tap on position 5 i need to scroll to position + 1 and backwards.
```

You can implement interface to get callback to activity or fragment about `itemClicked(int position)`

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

On Activity or fragment, you will be implementing that interface

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position){
        if(position == ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()) .findLastVisibleItemPosition()){
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position + 1);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: with 

`mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);`

it scrolls only to last item.

Comment: @AngleV ...?? Any Confusion ?

Comment: i think i did not explained it right. 

If user tap on an item that its close to the right edge of the recyclerview the recyclerview must scroll to the left and expose the next available item.
Now If user tap on an item closed to the left side of recyclerview it must scroll to the right.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue. In my own case, I have list of (nested) comments/replies and once I scroll down the list, the last item on the **RecyclerView** which has more content automatically scrolls to the right without allowing me to scroll left.

Once I wrapped the **RecyclerView** inside a **NestedScrollView** and setting `overScrollMode="never"`, the scrolling behaviour was normal.

*Hope this helps.*